# How to test monaco editor's monarch tokenizer?

Tags: tokenize, monaco-editor

The [monarch docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) are straightforward, but I'd like to test different patterns against my tokenizer. Is there an official way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3):

After an exhaustive search for an existing solution, I've found none, so I decided to create my own system. You can find the implementation here: https://github.com/adamgen/monarch-tester.

Comment: Apologies for not paying you bounty for this - it expired while I was on holiday :(